# regex code to remove periods

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

```
Dim wr_str as string

Dim str as string = "Introduction........................1"

Dim no As Match = Regex.Match(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\s*)([0-9]+)\s*$")

wr_str = Regex.Replace(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\s*)([0-9]+)\s*$", no.groups(1).value & no.groups(3).value)
```

---

```
Input string = "Introduction........................1"
```

I require the output string as 'Introduction;1'.

Could you please let me know how to change the regex expression to ignore the dots after the text

Comment: What's wrong with replacing one or more dots with semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this will do:

```
wr_str = Regex.Replace(wr_str, "\\.+", ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use capturing groups like this:

```
Dim myMatch = Regex.Match("Introduction.............1", "(^.*?)\.*([0-9]+)\s*$")
Dim res2 = myMatch.Groups(1).Value + ";" + myMatch.Groups(2).Value
```

Dots are captured with `\.*`, and are not used for final string creation.

EDIT: To match your code context:

```
Dim no as Match = Regex.Match("Introduction.............1", "(^.*?)\.*([0-9]+)\s*$")
wr_str = Regex.Replace(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\.*)([0-9]+)\s*$", no.Groups(1).Value.Replace(".", "").Trim() & ";" & no.groups(2).value)
```

Comment: Dim no as Match = Regex.Match("Introduction.............1", "(^.*?)\.*([0-9]+)\s*$") wr_str = Regex.Replace(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\.*)([0-9]+)\s*$", no.Groups(1).Value.Replace(".", "").Trim() & ";" & no.groups(2).value)

Comment: thansk for all of ur comments

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest form, this should work:

```
Dim wr_str as string

Dim str as string = "Introduction........................1"

Dim no As Match = Regex.Match(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\.*)([0-9]+)\s*$")

wr_str = Regex.Replace(wr_str, "(^.*?)(\.*)([0-9]+)\s*$", no.groups(1).value & ";" & no.groups(3).value)
```

The regex was matching on whitespace, not dots.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern (ignorecase+multiline):

```
^(.*?)\.*?(\d+)$
```

See more - [regex tester](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=XiguKj8pXC4qPyhcZCspJA%3D%3D&t=SW50cm9kdWN0aW9uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uMQ0KVGVzdC4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uMg0KV2FybmluZy4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4z&op=3)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gZBt.png